# Linux Command line Help | extract specific parts from file

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, grep

Suppose I have a log which has data in the format given below

```
        Time           number status  
2013-5-10 19:18:43.430 123456 success 
2013-5-10 19:28:13.430 134324 fail 
2013-5-10 19:58:33.430 456456 success
```

I want to extract the `numbers` having `success` status. 
Is there any way in linux using command line(grep, sed) to extract the data as mentioned. ??
Thanks all ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prints numbers based on success status-:

```
 awk '$4 ~ /success/ {print $3}' logfile
```

Answer (score 2):

**grep only** solution:

```
grep -Po '\d+(?= success)' file
```

or with **awk only**:

```
awk '$4=="success"&&$0=$3' input
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file | grep success | awk '{print $3}'
```

Comment: A cat? You're wearing out the keyboard and the PIDs with that extra program.

Comment: So what? Will it kill your CPU? I've given a working solution without even looking into `man`. Sure, you can achieve the same with a number of other standard tools, and even with the `awk` alone. There is always a room for improvement, everywhere, but it does not mean that the solution will be more elegant and readable.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
(grep 'success' | cut -d ' ' -f 3) <$file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using perl:

```
perl -ne '/success/ && split && print "$_[2]\n"' inputfile
```